# how can I swap a random index from a list in scala?

Tags: scala, list, swap

I know how to do like this when you know which values to swap

```
val li: List[Int] = List(1.1,2.2,3.1, 1.11, 2.1)

li.updated(0,li(2)).updated(2,li(0))
```

But, how about if you wanna swap completely 2 random indexes, how would you do that??

Comment: I'm not familiar with scala but I bet you can generate a random number in it then use it as the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val li: List[Double] = List( . . )

val x = util.Random.nextInt(li.length)
val y = util.Random.nextInt(li.length)

li.updated(x,li(y)).updated(y,li(x))
```

Note: There might be no swap when `x` == `y` but this is still safe, even for a small `List`.